# Apache2 upload timeout

Tags: apache-2.2, timeout, upload

Whenever an upload takes longer than 22 seconds, then the upload ends up with `connection was reset` error. On the server side, the connection is in `FIN_WAIT2` state. 
The problem is, that apache2 `Timeout` is 300 seconds, `max_input_time` is 60 seconds.

I have no idea what else can be causing this.

Comment: Are you using a php file to upload files ?

Comment: Yes .. I tried several scripts .. and even php file manager (http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/) failed.

Answer (score 1):

To upload files using `php` you have to consider these settings in your `php.ini` file :

- [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)
- [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)
- [max_input_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time)
- [memory_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)

As a sample, my production server for file upload is setup like this :

```
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
post_max_size = 2000M
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 3092M
```

Comment: All of that is OK - when I change to https then everything is working correctly. So I guess it's a problem on my ISP's side, I hope they will be able to fix it.